# How to use state parameter in RESTful services for XSRF/CSRF prevention with OIDC auth flow

Tags: javascript, rest, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

The page https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect advises how can we maintain state in session on the service for retrieving it and validating later once we obtain auth code from OP.
But how to do maintain state in a RESTful service which is stateless ? Please help.

Code like request.session().attribute("state", state) wont work there.
I am using .net core webapi for services and JavaScript for UI development

Comment: Not every aspect of your REST service needs to be stateless. Don't worry about a little bit of state, other parts of your stack will also have state.

Comment: you could use a [JWT](https://jwt.io/), with a period of time, and in every request must be sent on a header (Authorization) with the token, evaluate the token and if is valid, then continue the process.

Comment: Evert, another thing is that the flow reaches my Service after auth code is obtained from OP (OIDC provider). If state is not saved on Server then how to compare & validate it ? Should I first save state on my server and then redirect browser to the OP ?

Comment: To the Token-based authentication, to prevent the (XSRF/CSRF) attacks, you can store the token in browser's local storage. Besides, in asp.net core application, it will use the Antiforgery to prevent the (XSRF/CSRF) attacks. You can check this article: [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: @Zhi Lv mine is not an ASP.NET MVC Application. Its a JavaScript front end with Web API as back end. The way I resolved the issue, I have mentioned in the answers. But thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state in an encrypted cookie, for example. And in ASP.NET Core, the data stored in the session cookie is encrypted using the Data Protection API.

But in general, you should use the built-in dedicated Google authentication handler, as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0
Then it is all handled for you.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks @Tore Nestenius but the the flow reaches the .net core Service after auth code is obtained from OP (OIDC provider). If state is not saved on Server then how to compare & validate it ? Or, should I first call a service method to save the state in server cookie and then redirect browser/user to the OP ?

Comment: Besides state, you should also remember the nonce value. Typically you solve this issue by using sticky sessions, so the same instance is involved in the overall login flow.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I did. I created an end point which I invoke (before redirecting to OP) to generate the state and also return an http only cookie. Next when I make a service call (like) to retrieve token for authcode I pass state (retrieved from URL) and the httponly cookie to the service. The service EP validates that the state obtained from the cookie and the one passed in the body are equal. If its same then we are good otherwise it rejects that request.